# Delay showing div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, toolbar, delay

I have a floating/static toolbar that I would like to delay until the visitor has scrolled down the page some distance. I have tried using delay() and scroll() functions, but without success. It's possible I'm on the right trail, but incorrect syntax.

Say, for example, this is my toolbar (below)...what would I need in the script to delay showing it (javascript/jquery)? And, while we're at it, any way to fade it open?

```
<div class="toolbar">
<ul></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JQuery script below would reveal the toolbar div when the user scrolls the page.

NOTE: The page must be scrollable for the event to fire so the page content must be higher taller than the window.

```
<script>
  $(window).scroll(function () { 
    $(".toolbar").fadeIn("slow"); 
  });
</script>
```

This script would fade the toolbar div in after a pre-set delay.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () { 
    $(".toolbar").delay(800).fadeIn(10000); 
  });
</script>
```

Place either of the scripts directly above the closing `</body>` tag of your page and ensure you have a link to the JQuery library in your `<head>` section

Comment: Thank you. I was close, but this makes sense. However, I must have a jquery conflict as the script does not work.

Comment: Take a look at these example I made. The toolbar element must be hidden on load. 

http://benjaminhopkins.co.uk/stackoverflow/load.html

http://benjaminhopkins.co.uk/stackoverflow/scroll.html

Comment: I forgot about adding display:none...doh! I did notice that I still do have a jquery conflict though. W/o adding the specific js script, it does not work. However, if I add the js script, it functions as you created, but other jquery-based functionality on the site stops working, specifically prettyPhoto and tubepress. This site is WP-based, and the theme I use has built-in prettyPhoto js. I think I may need to start another question to help compress all the jquery statements and uses.